# Why is Visual Studio 2010 "Requesting Data"?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a strange problem that I see when switching to the ASP.NET designer in VS2010. It doesn't happen every time but once it's happened once it continues every time until I reboot.

Basically, when I click the "Design" button/tab to switch from the HTML to the designer, the text "Requesting Data..." appears in the status bar and the mouse pointer changes to and arrow with a spinning wait indicator. When this happens, the mouse continues to work but the keyboard input starts to fail. I can usually type but can't backspace or delete and I can't cut, copy or paste. Every other application continues to function normally so it's isolated to VS2010. It's also only affecting the designer. If I hit the "Source" button/tab to go back to the HTML, everything returns to normal.

This happens on really basic pages. My pages have a master page but the master page and the normal pages only contain basic html tags and the odd ASP.NET textbox or button.

Comment: The design mode in visual studio has never been the best, I tend to avoid it, perhaps thats the answer :-)

Comment: I do too but the job I'm doing requires lots of text editing and it's so much easier in design mode.

Comment: Jimbob, as m.edmondson suggested, it is better to avoid the design mode in VS. It is as if "enter at your own risk!".

Comment: Could it be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553147/vs2008-partially-freezing-when-switching-to-html-design-view/7637088#7637088 ? If not, there are some debugging tips there to help track it down.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why that message shows, but as a workaround, perhaps just create a static htm page in your site, go to design mode, do you editing/formatting, then copy paste the source into the real file?

one guess for message is if there is some sort of data source on the page or in the master page?