# Why is Visual Studio 2010 crashing in the HTML designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Fairly consistently when I'm using the HTML designer for editing ASP.NET files that contain essentially text and paragraphs, usually after a prolonged "Requesting data..." in the status bar, Visual Studio 2010 will just crash completely. No error message is shown, only the usual Visual Studio has encountered a problem dialog.

I have two extensions installed - PowerCommands and Productivity Power Tools. No other plugins. I'm fairly sure (though not 100%) that it crashed before these were installed too.

Here's an example event log:

> Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba1fab3
>   Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x72006500
>   Faulting process id: 0x5c8
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01cbbce486b11b94
>   Faulting application path: c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
>   Faulting module path: unknown
>   Report Id: 0999f614-28d8-11e0-81d1-6cf04975111f

### EDIT

I may have found the problem. Someone had installed the spelling checker extension from the extension manager in Visual Studio. I've uninstalled it and since have had no crashes.

Comment: Are you working with a page preview, and are you using any complex controls? Found [this](http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/40509/257659.aspx) on Google which sounds like it's related to controls on the page (and [your old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768932/why-is-visual-studio-2010-requesting-data) that didn't get answered) and / or missing CSS

Comment: Hi Rup. No, the pages only have basic tags - p, h1, h2, h3 and the odd img. There's a search box but that's just a textbox and a bit of javascript that does a redirect when you press Enter.